# Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using SpringBoot, and I'm trying to generate a report using Jasper Report 6.4.3, but keep getting this warning on console:

> WARN 25847 --- [tp1694467519-34] n.s.j.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer     : Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering

And I can't get the report generated.

Comment: The warning message signaled that you should put right version of iText (you can check version at pom.xml) to the classpath

Answer (score 8):

Jasper uses a special version of iText: **2.1.7.js4**

Correct version can be downloaded [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/maven2/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js4/)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry: I use jasper report 6.7.0. In the maven dependency I see they use iText 2.1.7.js6. Now With maven I have declared as dependency iText version 2.1.7. But I got always the WARN: n.s.j.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer     : Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering. I didn't understand how I can avoid them.....What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi. I found this link: (http://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/2.1.7.js6/) Maybe it helps

Comment: how did you resolve this, I'm getting the same warning and my report is not getting generated.

Comment: @Ruch i solved by using the specific version of iText i linked above. Beware that iText 2.1.7.js4 is not the same as iText 2.1.7. It is in fact a **js4** version made for *jasper studio*

Comment: btw new version of iText for *jasper studio* are available 

https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/ui/native/third-party-ce-artifacts/com/lowagie/itext/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am not passing the right parameter to Jesper to generate JesperPrint. Error is not giving correctly in console when data is not printing on output Jesper PDF.
Now after giving right parameter it is also showing this massage but my data is printing correcly.

I have used these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```